# possible situation where we should use pg_send_query in place of pg_query

Tags: php, postgresql

What are the best possible situations where we should use `pg_send_query` in place of `pg_query`?

Many times we just need to fire a query and don't require the query result, which is one possible situation I think. Although query failed or succeed can be required at some point later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the PHP [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-send-query.php):

> pg_send_query() sends a query or queries asynchronously to the connection. Unlike pg_query(), it can send multiple queries at once to PostgreSQL and get the results one by one using pg_get_result().

If you wanted to send multiple queries at once then `pg_send_query()` might be useful for you.  It would allow you to send multiple queries to Postgres in a single call.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send multiple queries to PostgreSQL, the best choice would be to choose **pg_send_query()**, alternatively if you are executing a single query **pg_query()** is useful.
Also, using pg_send_query() you need to fetch the result using pg_get_result() to get the result asynchronously as pg_send_query() also sends a asynchronous query to the connection.